# How to change colors on any PrimeNG module in Angular2 using CSS?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am working on an Angular2 project and my application is mostly built with the PrimeNG framework delivered by the same company that creates PrimeFaces.

I ran into a problem, where I want to customize the colors and the overall appearance of an [Accordion](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/accordion) panel, and I can't figure out how to get it done with the styleClass property.

Where should I set it? WebStorm doesn't seem to like it if I do it this way:

```
<p-accordionTab header="Personal Information" styleClass="myStyleClass">
Content
</p-accordionTab>
```

Furthermore, I'd love to know how should I craft my CSS in order to make it work?

Appreciate your input! :)

Comment: You got any answer?

Answer (score 1):

I am working with primeng as well and the way it should work based on your example is the following:

```
p-accordionTab.myStyleClass {
  width: 500px;
}
```

BUT there are a lot of bugreport that styleClass is not working properly.
So I advise you to use the default style classes primeng defines:

```
ui-accordion
ui-accordion-header
ui-accordion-content
```

so using them like this in style.css is working for me:

```
.ui-accordion {
  width: 500px
}
```

You can define your .css file in your angular-cli.json the following way:

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css"
]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: @balag3 i have tried your approach but this is not working for me. I have spent almost 2 hrs in that.

Answer (score 0):

if your looking for easy ngClass solution
here's a small example

```
(..)
<p-accordionTab [selected]="true" [ngClass]="elementFilter ? 'highLightFoundElement' : ''">
(...)

:host ::ng-deep .highLightFoundElement > div > a{
    background-color: blueviolet !important; //your choice colour
}
```